# Correct format of syslog messages to be transmitted over UDP to syslog server?

Tags: c, debugging, logging, syslog

I have implemented a syslog client in C, but I'm getting inconsistent results when it comes to different syslog servers displaying the syslog message.

So I'm hoping that there's somebody out there who could tell me what the format should look like.

The format I am using looks like this:

```
msgLen = sprintf_s(syslogMessage, 1024, "<%d>%d %s %s     [%s] : ", priority, version,
timestamp, hostname, applicationName);

vsnprintf(syslogMessage + msgLen , 1024 - msgLen , syslogMessage, ap);
```

It would be greatly appreciated, if somebody could show me how a syslog message should be formated in C.

I calculate priority as priority = severity_level + 8*facility_level

The 'version' is equal to 1.

The 'timestamp' is generated as:

```
GetLocalTime(&stm);
sprintf_s(timestamp, 128, "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%dZ", stm.wYear,
stm.wMonth, stm.wDay, stm.wHour, stm.wMinute, stm.wSecond, stm.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: There is no 100% consistent definition.  As noted in the appendix A.1 of RFC 5424, "The only thing that all of them agree upon is that messages start with "<" PRIVAL ">".  Other than that, legacy syslog messages are not formatted in a consistent way."  Can you describe some specific issues you are seeing that you're seeing?  Not all syslog servers will interpret messages the same way due to this standard-by-accident.